# Evaluate the following: $(1-i)^{1+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My progression:

$(1-i)^{i+1} = e^{(i+1) * \ln(1-i)}$. I get stuck after this point.

Comment: How do you define $\ln(1-i)$?

Comment: Can you evaluate $\ln (1-i)$ ?

Comment: $ln(1-i) = ln(\sqrt{2}e^{i\arctan(-1/1)}) = ln(\sqrt{2}) + i7\pi/4?$

Comment: So now you can evaluate $(i+1) \ln(1-i)$, and after that your expression.

Comment: Note that this expression has an infinite number of values.

Comment: $(i + 1)\ln(1-i) = (\ln(\sqrt{2}) + 7\pi/4)i + (\ln(\sqrt{2}) - 7\pi/4)$... I believe.

Comment: $\ldots+2\pi ki(i+1)$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hence, we get $e^{\ln(\sqrt{2}) - 7\pi/4}(\cos(\ln(\sqrt{2}) + 7\pi/4) + i\sin(\ln(\sqrt{2}) + 7\pi/4))$.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot to include that last part. We do that because $\ln(1-i)$ will have a $2\pi k i$ that we will need to distribute the $i+1$ into, yes?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The Maple code $$ simplify(evalc((1-I)^{1+I}), exp, ln);$$ produces $$\sqrt {2}e^{1/4\,\pi }\sin \left( 1/2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +
1/4\,\pi  \right) -i\sqrt {2}{ e^{1/4\,\pi }}\sin \left( -1/2\,
\ln  \left( 2 \right) +1/4\,\pi  \right)
 $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $z^w$ where $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$ is not uniquely determined. In fact, we **define**
$$z^w = e^{w\log z}$$
where $\log z$ is **any** logarithm of $z$. There are infinitely many choices of $\log z$, and for most values of $z$ and $w$ there will be infinitely many possible values for $z^w$.

To get something unique, you will have to specify a particular *branch* of the complex logarithm, but when you do so. $z^w$ won't be defined for all $z$ (or at the very least $z^w$ won't be continuous in $z$, depending on what your conventions with branches are).

In your particular case $\log(1-i) = \ln \sqrt 2 - \dfrac{i\pi}4 + 2\pi i k$ for some arbitrary integer $k$, and

\begin{align}
(1-i)^{1+i} &= e^{(1+i)\log(1-i)} \\
&= e^{(1+i)(\ln \sqrt 2 - \frac{i\pi}4 + 2\pi i k)} \\
&= e^{ \ln \sqrt 2 + \frac\pi4-2\pi k + i(\ln\sqrt 2 - i\frac{\pi}4 + 2\pi k)} \\
&= \sqrt 2 e^{\frac\pi4-2\pi k\pi}\cdot e^{i(\ln\sqrt2-\frac\pi4)} \\
&= \sqrt 2 e^{\frac\pi4-2\pi k\pi}\cdot \big( \cos (\ln\sqrt2-\frac\pi4) + i \sin(\ln\sqrt2-\frac\pi4) \big) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Dutifully upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln\left((1-i)^{(1+i)}\right)=(1+i)\ln(1-i)=(1+i)\left[\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)-\frac{1}{4}i\pi\right]$$
So:
$$\ln[(1-i)^{(1+i)}]=F=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)(1+i)+\frac{1}{4}\pi(1-i)$$
and:
$$(1-i)^{(1+i)}=\exp(F)$$
and then:
$$(1-i)^{(1+i)}=(1+i)\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)\right)-i\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)\right)\right)\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi\right)$$

Comment: How did you go from $(1-i)^{1+i}$ to $(1-i)\ln(1+i)$?

Comment: @String: I agree. I correct it right now

Comment: @David: Sorry. It was a mistake. I just corrected it

Comment: This is still incorrect.

Comment: @mrf: corrected it

Comment: Read your first line again. You are claiming that $a^b = b\ln a$.

Comment: @mrf: Ok. Never give an answer if you are busy...Thanks anyway.

Comment: You might want to have a look at some other answers to see the *mathematical* problem with this one.

Answer (score -1):

$n \in {\mathbb Z}$.

\begin{align}
\left(1 - {\rm i}\right)^{1 + {\rm i}}
&=
\left[\sqrt{2\,}\,{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\left(-\pi/4 + 2n\pi\right)}\right]
^{1 + {\rm i}}
=
\left(\sqrt{2\,}\,\right)^{1 + {\rm i}}
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\left(-\pi/4 + 2n\pi\right) - \left(-\pi/4 + 2n\pi\right)}
\\[3mm]&=
\sqrt{2\,}\,{\rm e}^{\pi/4 - 2n\pi}\,
\left(\sqrt{2\,}\,\right)^{\rm i}
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\left(-\pi/4 + 2n\pi\right)}
=
\left(1 - {\rm i}\right){\rm e}^{\pi/4 - 2n\pi}\,
2^{{\rm i}/2}
\\[3mm]&=
{\rm e}^{\pi/4 - 2n\pi}\,
{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\ln\left(2\right)/2}\left(1 - {\rm i}\right)
=
{\rm e}^{\pi/4 - 2n\pi}\,
\left[%
\cos\left({1 \over 2}\ln\left(2\right)\right)
+
{\rm i}\sin\left({1 \over 2}\ln\left(2\right)\right)
\right]\left(1 - {\rm i}\right)
\\
----&------------------------------------
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&n \in {\mathbb Z}\,,
\\[5mm]
&\color{#ff0000}{\left(1 - {\rm i}\right)^{1 + {\rm i}}}
\\&=
\color{#ff0000}{{\rm e}^{\pi/4 - 2n\pi}\times
\left\{%
\left[
\cos\left({1 \over 2}\ln\left(2\right)\right)
+
\sin\left({1 \over 2}\ln\left(2\right)\right)\right]
+
{\rm i}\left[%
-\cos\left({1 \over 2}\ln\left(2\right)\right)
+
\sin\left({1 \over 2}\ln\left(2\right)\right)\right]
\right\}}
\end{align}